# Tomcat server ran into 404 for unknown reason

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to use Maven to run on Tomcat 8 as server. I'm newbie to these two, so I have an example file which I haven't made, and is supposed to print 'welcome'.
However, I receive this error

> The requested resource is not available.

I checked TomCat log on my IDE (Netbeans) and I found out it gives this errors:

> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   26-May-2017 19:22:50.151 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-76] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet court as unavailable
>   26-May-2017 19:22:50.151 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-76] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [court] in web application [/ronak] threw load() exception
>    **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet**
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:490)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1027)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:461)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1612)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1451)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:897)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My problem is that, the line I made it bold says I don't have this repository :org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in my project. However, I'm sure it can be seen in my dependencies.The file spring-webmvc.4.3.8.Release.jar is visible in the expected folder(WEB-INF/lib) and it contains a class file named DispatcherServlet.class which is accessible in my project window in netbeans.

I also checked to POM file, and I have these which declare this file-and two other spring web jar files- as dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <!-- Set this to the respective version -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

So, is there anything I'm doing wrong here? since TomCat doesn't provide any further info to tell exactly what couldn't be found, the only problem I see is this.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: you have scope provided in spring-mvc dependency

Comment: I've checked all possible alternatives of <scope> , but no change happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if there are libs in your artefact (war). If pom.xml is configured incorrectly, some libs might absent there.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get what you meant. If you mean to check myproject.war file, its content is not human readable. Could you please explain more? thanks!

Comment: you can open myproject.war with winrar (it is just archive) and find \WEB-INF\lib folder. your libs must be there.

Comment: Thanks. I can see spring-web, but there is no spring-webmvc there. So how should I change my POM.xml?

Comment: try to remove scope tag and rebuild artefact.

Comment: I Tried it, no change :-?

Comment: firstly i would check that "<packaging>war</packaging>" is in pom.xml.
secondly i would try to build with maven's commands (clean, compile, package), if you do not.
thirdly, In intelij idea there is "artefacts" menu item in settings of project where i can see rules of build based on pom.xml, I would check there
perhaps there is something similar in netbeans (unfortunatly, I dont use netbeans). Fourthly, I would remove all out of out folder

Comment: It seems that Maven commands worked and no more ClassNotFoundException is seen now, Thanks!:)